# How to set the default program without the program's icon for an extension

Tags: windows-registry, file-extension, regedit

This might not be the best place to ask, but how can I set the default program for an extension while using a custom icon handler from a dll? I used [this tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=577735) to show an apk's icon in explorer. I also want to use apks with 7-Zip, but I can't do both at the same time.

I currently have this setup that I just import into the registry, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk]
@="Android Package File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\apkshellext]
@="{66391a18-f480-413b-9592-a10044de6cf4}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\shellex\IconHandler]
@="{66391a18-f480-413b-9592-a10044de6cf4}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\shellex\{00021500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@="{66391a18-f480-413b-9592-a10044de6cf4}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\shellex\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\shellex\{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}]
@="{c5aec3ec-e812-4677-a9a7-4fee1f9aa000}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\OpenWithList]
"a"="7zFM.exe"
"MRUList"="a"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\UserChoice]
"Progid"="Applications\\7zFM.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk\OpenWithProgids]
"Android Package File"=hex(0):
```

Comment: Have you tried asking the apkshellext dev if this is even possible? You can also add something like "Open with 7-zip" to the context menu for .APK files.

Comment: @Karan I've been trying to play around with the registry, but no luck :/. I'll try to contact the dev if I can't figure anything out.

Comment: Well? Did you ever figure out how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I gave up on the project years ago, but I'm looking into it now to see if I might be able to try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Windows 8 file type icon](http://superuser.com/questions/622715/changing-windows-8-file-type-icon)

Comment: This link should have your answer. Just set (default) to SHELLFILE, Icon # (remember, the first on is 0 and second is 1 and so on)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use custom icons after associating archives with 7-Zip. Check my Registry entry below for reference. My example is for ISO files which are associated with WinRAR. Eventhough my ISO files are associated with WinRAR, I am able to use a custom file icon for it.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.iso]
@="ISOfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ISOfile]
@="ISO image"
"FriendlyTypeName"="ISO"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ISOfile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Myfolder\\repository\\image\\icon\\filetype\\iso.ico,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ISOfile\shell]
@="Open"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ISOfile\shell\open]
@="&Open"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ISOfile\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe \"%1\""
```

In your case, go to the key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Android Package File
```

Then edit the contents of the sub-key: **DefaultIcon**. If it does not exists, create a sub-key under **Android Package File**, and name it DefaultIcon.

Now go inside of DefaultIcon and put the full path of your icon file (ico, exe, dll, etc).